# How to access a Network Mounted Volume in .NET Core File.Open

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, macos

I'm trying to open a File from a Mounted Network Volume in a .NET Core 6 Console app on a MAC. In Windows I can simply use "N:/myfolder/myfile.txt" if the Network drive is mounted to N:/. How can I open the File on MAC using a mounted Volume?

```
var file = File.Open("/VOLUMEHERE/Media1/Images", FileMode.Open);
```

Answer (score 0):

Access is possible using
//Volumes/VolumeName/...

```
var file = File.Open("//Volumes/Media1/placeholder.jpg", FileMode.Open);
```